# flextable: embed ggpplots using data from 2 columns with lists (for comparing) as a single plot per row

Tags: r, ggplot2, flextable

Following https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/cell-content-1.html#base-plots-and-ggplot-objects I would like to have small plots.

```
   gg_line <- function(z) {
  z <- scale(z)
  z <- na.omit(z)
  z <- data.frame(x = seq_along(z), z = z)
  ggplot(z, aes(x = x, y = z)) +
    geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
    theme_void()
}
```

Build a dataset, embed a list with data.

```
  dat <- as.data.table(mtcars)
z <- dat[,
         lapply(.SD, function(x) list(gg_line(x))),
         by = c("vs", "am"), .SDcols = c("mpg", "disp")
]
```

Replace ggplot data in cells with plots.

```
  ft <- flextable(z)
ft <- compose(ft, 
              j = c("mpg", "disp", "drat"),
              value = as_paragraph(gg_chunk(value = ., height = .15, width = 1)),
              use_dot = TRUE
)
ft
```

As a result I have 2 columns with plots.

[image]

I am wondering how to change the code so that instead of two columns one is produced:  **one ggplot per row with superimposed two geoms** (in this case for "mpg" and "disp" but this could be **two groups present in the dataset** like two companies, two species). I wish I could plot **side by side in each cell two boxplots or two violin plots in one cell**. Is there an easy way to combine two lists, from two columns, to generate one column with a single plot per each record that shows data from two lists (two layers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I lack the `data.table` skills to do the data wrangling via `data.table` but making use of the `tidyverse` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(flextable)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

gg <- function(z, cols, type = "box") {
  z <- z[, cols]
  z <- dplyr::mutate(z, dplyr::across(all_of(cols), scale), x = seq(nrow(z)))
  z <- na.omit(z)
  z <- tidyr::pivot_longer(z, -x)
  
  geom <- switch(type,
                 line = geom_line(aes(x = x), show.legend = FALSE),
                 box = geom_boxplot(aes(x = name), show.legend = FALSE, size = .1))
  ggplot(z, aes(y = value, color = name)) +
    geom +
    theme_void()
}

dat <- mtcars
dat <- dat %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = -c(vs, am)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    line = lapply(data, function(x) gg(x, cols = c("mpg", "disp"), "line")),
    box = lapply(data, function(x) gg(x, cols = c("mpg", "disp"), "box"))) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-data)

ft <- flextable(dat[, c("vs", "am", "line")])
ft <- compose(ft, 
              j = c("line"),
              value = as_paragraph(gg_chunk(value = ., height = .15, width = 1)),
              use_dot = TRUE
)
ft
```

[image]

```r
ft <- flextable(dat[, c("vs", "am", "box")])
ft <- compose(ft, 
              j = c("box"),
              value = as_paragraph(gg_chunk(value = ., height = .15, width = 1)),
              use_dot = TRUE
)
ft
```

[image]